# Are nested HTML lists deprecated?

Tags: html

The HTML 4 spec [treats the following as a deprecated example](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) (search for "DEPRECATED EXAMPLE"):

```
<UL>
     <LI> ... Level one, number one...
     <OL> 
        <LI> ... Level two, number one...
        <LI> ... Level two, number two...
        <OL start="10"> 
           <LI> ... Level three, number one...
        </OL> 
        <LI> ... Level two, number three...
     </OL> 
     <LI> ... Level one, number two...
</UL>
```

Why is this example deprecated?

Comment: My guess is that the example is deprecated because one of the `<ol>` includes the deprecated `start` attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `start` attribute is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#adef-start) in HTML 4 (it is [un-deprecated in HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-ol-start)). Everything else about the example is fine.

Comment: I found the other answers very informative, but I believe you're right, so here goes my humble green check mark. It's puzzling how elements and attributes become deprecated and later "pardoned"!

Comment: HTML 4 attempted to design a clean specification that neatly separated concerns. HTML 5 gave up on that after people learned HTML from awful tutorials and mostly just documented what people were actually writing.

Comment: I could see how what you say applies to the readmitted `U` and `S` elements, but why would you deprecate the `start` attribute? It seems to be useful, if somewhat redundant when `LI`s have `value` attributes. EDIT: Wait! The also deprecated `value` for `LI`s in the same sapec! Go figure...

Comment: @eze — Replaced by CSS counters.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin. I didn't know about those! I still feel the `start` attribute is more content than presentation, unlike the clearly historical `type` attribute for `OL`.

Answer (score 6):

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists#Nesting_lists) details the proper way to nest `ul` and `ol` elements. They must be encased in an `li` element, as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <ol>
          <li>Hello there</li>
       </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However in your example, the lists are not wrapped in an `li` tag, meaning that it would fail HTML validation.

Comment: The lists **are** wrapped in an `li`. The indenting is just bad and it is taking advantage of the rule that end tags for `li` elements are optional.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, chrisopher. I believe the linked document is a wiki more than a spec, and in any case `OL` is inside the first `LI`. It would be great if the specs included a clarifying note...

Comment: I was tempted to fix the indenting, but after all that is how it is presented in the spec.